# Compass Error "Could not determine font type" when using font-face()

Tags: css, fonts, compass-sass

I'm trying to import a font with [Compass's font-face function](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/font_face/). I give the following instruction:

```
@include font-face("Avenir", font-files("Avenir.ttc"));
```

And the get the following error:

```
error assets/styles/sass/styles.scss (Line 1 of assets/styles/sass/_typography.scss: Could not determine font type for "Avenir.ttc")
```

I have not specified the `fonts_dir` in my config.rb file, but my font files are placed in `<css_styles>/fonts` directory, which according to the documentation linked above is the default location.

Anyone know what might be going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Compass is not recognizing the ttc extension, you should use one of the extensions defined in the CSS 3 fonts specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#src-desc